# Add validation to date field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, validation, date

I have a database with a table inside MySQL. I want to add some validation to the date field. I want it to only accept dates in the future (including today).

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this have to be done from the mySQL side?   How are the values being entered in to the database?   For example, if they are coming from a website, it's much easier to validate from php...  etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that comes to mind is to have a trigger or stored procedure that checks the date before the insertion.